# Google Vertex AI fails AutoML training due to large BigQuery dataset being too large

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am currently training some models via Googles AutoML feature contained within their Vertex AI products.

The normal pipeline is creating a dataset, which I do by creating a table in Bigquery, and then starting the training process.

This has normally worked before but for my latest dataset I get the following error message:

> Training pipeline failed with error message: The size of source BigQuery table is larger than 107374182400 bytes.

While it seemed unlikely to me that the table is actually too large for AutoML, I tried re-training on a new dataset that's a 50% sample of the original table but the same error occured.

Is my dataset really to large for AutoML to handle or is there another issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some perspectives of limits for AutoML Tables -- not only size in bytes (100GB as maximum supported size), but also number of rows (~200bi lines) and number of columns (up to 1000 columns).

You can find more details on [AutoML Tables limits](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/quotas#limits) documentation.

Is your source data within those limits?

Comment: Row and column wise for sure but some columns are very dense text. How can I check the table size in bytes, is that simply available in table schema or details?

Comment: you can use the [TABLE_STORAGE view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-table-storage), from BigQuery Information Schema, to check the uncompressed size of your tables

```
SELECT
  table_name,
  total_rows,
  total_logical_bytes
FROM
  \`region-<REGION>\`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_STORAGE
ORDER BY
  total_logical_bytes DESC;
```

Comment: I wasn't able to run the command (lacking permissions) but the table details in the UI showed even the sampled table was over 100GB so I have to sample it down even further.